# file transfer after encryption

Tags: usb, encryption

I am a new Android user and I am considering encrypting my device for more security. My notebook runs Linux Mint and I have been transferring files to my Android (version 4.4) using the USB cable via Mint's default file manager Nemo. My question is: if I encrypt my device, will I be able to transfer files using the same method? And if I connect my device to other computers using the USB Mass Storage, will I also be able to see/add/remove files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely ! As long as you can unlock your device you can transfer files. Encryption works as usual but will encrypt the data but that doesn't mean you can't access it. Go for it ! Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

Most android phones have encryption by default id recommend reading this first. http://www.howtogeek.com/141953/how-to-encrypt-your-android-phone-and-why-you-might-want-to/

id also recommend adding a password verbal  or using numbers on the lock screen keep usb debugging off unless needed and look into a app that can locate your phone or remote wipe it if lost. such as Avast

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but nor what you wrote nor the link you gave me address the specific question I posted above which is about the method of file transferring I am currently using.